# How do you put custom skins in a console-playable edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

How do you put PC skins in Console Edition without hacking or editing the game files? I am asking because I want to use my Superchu skin on my PS4 and Xbox One. I want to do broadcasts with that skin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use custom skins on a console without hacking the game.

Comment: "There HAS to be a way!" ... Why?

Comment: @MCAydenBird you can't on consoles. PC is different because you got complete control over your computer and as such can use mods. Sony and Microsoft are MUCH more stringent about the content that comes on their consoles. They don't want e.g. someone appearing as a completely naked humanoid, mainly to protect children.

Comment: There is no possible way to do this, @MCAydenBird, since there simply isn't any support for that feature on consoles.

Answer (score 2):

As the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Skin#Console_Edition) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Skin&oldid=1204795)) says, you cannot use a self created skins in Console Edition. You can at least choose between 16 different skins in the default skin pack (under "Help & Options"->"Change Skin") and download additional [skin packs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Skin/Skin_packs) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Skin/Skin_pack&oldid=1186315)).

Comment: ...or just play the real Minecraft. ;)

Comment: My PC is dead, and I cannot find the charger.

Comment: It's a laptop, right? There should be text on it saying what model it is. Google that together with the word "charger" or "power cable" or something similar. You should be able to buy one without needing a new PC.

Comment: Found It! Yaaaaaaaaaaay.

Comment: Wrong brand...   ._.

Answer (score 2):

As the Console versions and PC versions are [different](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1274139-different-minecraft-editions), you are not allowed to use the skins interchangeably.

By the link I posted, the Xbox One skins can only be the ones bought at Xbox Live, the PS4 skins can only be the ones bought at the PSN Store, and the PC(Java or Windows 10) and Pocket the ones that allows the User Created Skins.

Comment: What about the update that will FUSE all MC Editions?

Comment: Maybe then they will update the version or will show generic skin for users that has no access to that skin

Answer (score 0):

the console edition of minecraft doesnt allow Custom skin's sadly
it does have skin packs which you can use
the defualt ones are already installed but the others are in the store

Comment: Btw I think if I enter the BT MC via PC, I can use custom Skins by using the 'Import Skin' feature on Windows 10